# Tkinter with matplotlib - Why is frame not drawing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to display a pie chart using matplotlib embedded in tkinter. Here's the class declaration:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, data, directory, scan_date, frame):
        self.data = data
        self.directory = directory
        self.scan_date = scan_date
        self.frame = frame

    def pie_chart(self):
        # try:
        #     self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack_forget()
        # except AttributeError:
        #     pass

        piechart = graphs.make_pie_chart(self.data, self.directory, self.scan_date)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(piechart, master=self.frame)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

And here's where it's instantiated:

```
def scan_and_display(directory):
    # runs the main scan function
    data, scanDate = main(directory)

    pie_frame = Frame(root, height=700, width=700)
    graph1 = Graph(data, directory, scanDate, pie_frame)
    graph1.pie_chart()
```

In the line `self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(piechart, master=self.frame)`, if I change `master` to `root`, it works. But I would like to embed it in its on frame so I can more easily add more elements as I continue building the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to layout the frame. Add this to the end:

```
pie_frame.pack()
```

Comment: wow, I feel like an idiot. I guess I thought that packing the canvas was the final step, forgot I actually have to pack the frame too. Thank you!